# 'int' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

Me dice

> 'int' object does not support item assignment

¿Por qué ocurre esto?

```
matriz=[0,0]
info=['111','222','444']
matriz[0][0]=int(info[2])
print(matriz)
```

Comment: el error se produce por querer asignar a un entero un número utiliando la notación de corchetes,  es lo mismo que hacer `1[0] = 2`

Comment: En realidad el error que tienes ocurre porque estás intentando indexar un array de una sola dimensión como si fuera un array de dos dimensiones. Intenta solamente `matriz[0]=int(info[2])` si lo que quieres es colocar 444 en la primera posición de `matriz`, de lo contrario, especifica en tu pregunta que es lo que necesitas.

Comment: Tu `matriz` tiene dos elementos. `matriz[0]` se refiere al primero de ellos, que vale 0. Pero al poner `matriz[0][0]` estás aplicando por segunda vez una indexación `[0]` al resultado que ya te había devuelto la primera. Así que estás haciendo lo mismo que  `0[0]`. Esa operación no tiene sentido, pues el entero `0` no tiene elementos internos (items) que puedas acceder usando `[0]`

Comment: ahí lo pude entender, muchas gracias Christian y Jaime.

Comment: perfecto, gracias por la explicación Abulafia.

Answer (score 0):

Esto `matriz=[0,0]` no crea una matriz sino una lista simple, por lo  cual `matriz[0]` es el primer 0 de la lista, es decir un entero, lo cual hace que no tenga sentido el siguiente índice, si lo ves de esta forma el error es claro en este sentido.

Para crear un lista de listas o matriz, deberías hacer algo así:

```
matriz=[[0],[0]]
```

Y ahora sí

```
info=['111','222','444']
matriz[0][0]=int(info[2])
print(matriz)

[[444], [0]]
```

Por último, si tienes que trabajar con matrices, Python base no es lo mejor en este sentido, es preferible optar por librerías como [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/)

Answer (score 0):

si lo que quieres e guardar un dato en matriz[] de info[] lo debes de hacer es lo sigiente:

introducir el código aqui

```
matriz=[0,0]
info=['111','222','444']
matriz.insert(0,info[2])
print(matriz)
```

donde matriz.insert(posicion lista matriz,dato lista info)

Comment: ¿Por qué `0, info[2]`? ¿Qué tal `1, info[0]`?

Comment: También lo puedes hacer matriz.insert( esta es la posicion del dato, info[dato que necesites] ) puedes jugar con los valores según lo que tengas en las listas y donde lo quieras acomodar